# Getting accurate request count

Tags: java, coldfusion, jvm, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I have this code for counting Requests:

```
<cfobject type="JAVA" action="Create" name="thread" class="java.lang.Thread">

<!--- Get all stack traces from the thread object --->
<cfset stackTrace = thread.getAllStackTraces()>

<!--- Convert the entrySet into an array --->
<cfset stackArray = stackTrace.entrySet().toArray()>

<cfset requestCount = 0 />

<!--- Loop over the entrySet array --->
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(stackArray)#" index="sIndex">
    <!--- Get the current thread values --->
    <cfset thisThread = stackArray[sIndex].getValue()>
    <!--- Loop over current thread values --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(thisThread)#" index="tIndex">
        <!--- Get the filename for this thread --->
        <cfset thisThreadFile = thisThread[tIndex].getFileName()>
        <!--- If the file name contains .cfm output it --->
        <cfif isDefined("thisThreadFile") AND thisThreadFile CONTAINS ".cfm">
            <cfset requestCount += 1 />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>

<cfset json_object = structNew()>
<cfset json_object["active_requests"] = JavaCast("int", requestCount)>

<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(json_object)#</cfoutput>
```

I need to be able to not count multiples on the stack trace. What would be the best way to do that?